# Hide function using block scope

Tags: javascript

In the past, if I want to hide a variable function, I can using IIFE

```
(function(){
    var _hiddenVariable = "_hiddenVariable";
    function _hiddenFunction(){
        //blablabla
    }
})();

console.log(_hiddenVariable); //error
_hiddenFunction(); //error
```

After ES6, I can use let and block scope to hide a variable, but function can't.

```
{
    let _hiddenVariable = "_hiddenVariable";
    function _hiddenFunction(){
        //blablabla
    }
}

console.log(_hiddenVariable); //error
_hiddenFunction(); //pass
```

Below is the only solution I can find.

```
{
    let _hiddenFunction = function(){
        //blablabla
    }
}

_hiddenFunction(); //error
```

So, two questions.

1. Is there another way to hide a function in block scope?
2. Is it a good idea that I use the solution above in all my projects? If not, can you suggest me a solution better than this?

thx

Comment: Why do you need another way? What's wrong with the IIFE method?

Comment: @GuyIncognito For me, I think "{}" is much more clean than "(function(){})()" when reading code. In this case, I just need a scope to prevent global pollution and hide my thing, it's useless to build a new function than execute it. So if a simple block scope can work, I'll prefer this than IIFE.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can hide the function by returning only what you want from an object.
Some

```js
class Character {
     
    constructor (name, weapon){
        this.name=name;
        this.weapon=weapon;
    }
    attack = function(){
        var that=this;
        that.varToSee=54    
        const age=()=>{
            return that.varToSee
        }
        that.receivedFunc=function (){
            return "Attack";
        }
        return {
            age: age
        }
    }
}

const shrek=new Character("Shrek", "cloth")
const receive =shrek.attack()
console.log(receive.age())
console.log(receive.receivedFunc())
```

You might see that receivedFunc will not be accessible.